# Rest Api creation in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I need to make a single api, by which I can return data format of json or xml, as it has been requested from the customer.

guys, any idea how I achieve this because when I use @Produces annotation it makes it fix for specific format, but I need to return as it has been requested.

Comment: Just define two different URLs separate for JSON and XML.

Comment: Additional query param. `format=json/xml`

Comment: Wow, 3 answer and you don't even care to accept one of them. Not that kind

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Spring, configure ContentNegotiationManager in DispatcherServlet.xml and then you can use response type as parameters to url.

For example:

http://localhost:8080/employee-management-system/viewEmployee/4?type=xml

http://localhost:8080/employee-management-system/viewEmployee/4?type=json

More detailed instructions you can find here:

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/rest4

Answer (score 0):

What I would normally expect to see here are two methods, one that `@Produces ("application/json")`, and the other that `@Produces("application/xml")`.

```
@Path("/foobar")
public final class FooBar {
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String xml () { ... }

    @Produces("application/json")
    public String json() { ... }
}
```

The example in Oracle's description of the [@Produces annotation](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs002.html#the-produces-annotation) includes an example for `text/plain` and `text/html` which is similar.

> this is one way to do it, but I don't want to write 2 methods. I want to do it in one method.

Another reasonable approach would be to get closer to the metal

```
@Path("/foobar")
public final class FooBar {
    public Response foobar() (@Context HttpHeaders headers) { ... }
}
```

And then inspect the headers yourself to decide what to do.  See [Get HTTP header in JAX-RS](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/)

Comment: this is one way to do it, but I don't want to write 2 methods. I want to do it in one method.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the response content type using the ResponseEntity object as follows:

```
return ResponseEntity
              .ok()
              .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
```